# Why does `count_over_time` increase without matching raw data?

Tags: prometheus, promql

... or "How does `count_over_time` work?"

Given the following vector and value:

```
kube_job_created{
  app="prometheus",
  chart="prometheus-7.1.0",
  component="kube-state-metrics",
  heritage="Tiller",
  instance="100.96.2.23:8080",
  job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",
  job_name="foobar-24150",
  kubernetes_name="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",
  kubernetes_namespace="devops",
  namespace="devops",
  nodename="ip-1-1-1-1.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",
  release="prometheus"
} 1538008393
```

Count over the entire vector returns `1`:

```
count(kube_job_created{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-7.1.0",component="kube-state-metrics",heritage="Tiller",instance="100.96.2.23:8080",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",job_name="braze-user-attribute-sync-24150",kubernetes_name="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",kubernetes_namespace="devops",namespace="devops",nodename="ip-10-10-4-112.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",release="prometheus"})
```

Result:

```
{} 1
```

Now, with `count_over_time` it's different depending on the range vector selector:

1m:

```
count_over_time(kube_job_created{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-7.1.0",component="kube-state-metrics",heritage="Tiller",instance="100.96.2.23:8080",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",job_name="braze-user-attribute-sync-24150",kubernetes_name="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",kubernetes_namespace="devops",namespace="devops",nodename="ip-10-10-4-112.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",release="prometheus"}[1m])
```

Result is "2":

```
{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-7.1.0",component="kube-state-metrics",heritage="Tiller",instance="100.96.2.23:8080",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",job_name="braze-user-attribute-sync-24150",kubernetes_name="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",kubernetes_namespace="devops",namespace="devops",nodename="ip-10-10-4-112.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",release="prometheus"} 2
```

- 1h returns 120
- 24h returns 2880

What exactly is it counting over time?

Comment: My first guess is blocks of 30 seconds, but as for why.... does match all your examples though 1 minute is 2*30 seconds, 1 hour is 60 minutes ie 60 * 2 is 120 and 1440 minutes * 2 ...etc...

Comment: Thank you Mike, that's my take on it too. But I would expect that it takes the time window (e.g. 24h) and counts all the vectors in it. Which should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count_over_time` counts the number of samples in the range, for each time series. Like all `_over_time` functions it works across all the samples of one time series at a time.

If you wanted the number of time series in an instant vector, then the `count` aggregator will tell you that.

Comment: Thanks Brian, just to clarify the `count_over_time` for:

   `foobar{app="test1"}
    foobar{app="test2"}`

Would be 2?